# How to find namespace XML avoid other name in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I have problem with parsing XML on jQuery. I have XML file like this

```
<field name="scheduleItems">
   <value>
     <field name="programID">364</field>
     <field name="programTime">05:00</field>
     <field name="programTimeEnd">05:30</field>
   <value>
</field>
```

And this is my code when use ajax for parsing

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: xmlFeed,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find("field[name*='scheduleItems']").each(function(i, obj){
             $(xml).find("value").each(function(i, obj){
                 var programTime = $(this).children("field[name*='programTime']").text();
                 var programTimeEnd = $(this).children("field[name*='programTimeEnd']").text();
              });
        });   
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log("has error!");
    }
 });
```

When I print result of **programTime**. **programTimeEnd** will append like this >> **"programTime":"05:0005:30"**

Can I resolve it. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `*=` that means "contains" and "programTimeEnd" contains "programTime". Use `=` for "equals".

```js
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xml = parser.parseFromString(
  '<field name="scheduleItems">'+
  '  <value>'+
  '  <field name="programID">364</field>'+
  '  <field name="programTime">05:00</field>'+
  '  <field name="programTimeEnd">05:30</field>'+
  '</value>'+
  '</field>',
  'application/xml'
);

var output = document.getElementById('output');
$(xml).find('field[name="scheduleItems"]').each(
  function(i, obj){
    $(this).find("value").each(
      function(i, obj){
        var programTime = $(this).children('field[name="programTime"]').text();
        var programTimeEnd = $(this).children('field[name="programTimeEnd"]').text();
        output.appendChild(
          document.createTextNode(
            programTime + ' - ' + programTimeEnd
          )
        );
        output.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
      }
    );
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Note: Your XML has no namespace and this is a good thing because jQuery has no support for XML namespaces.